# Error pops up when I want to compile it

Tags: errors, texmaker, compilation-error

```
xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

Does anyone know what this means. I can not open any preview? I use Texmaker on Windows.

Comment: that isn't an error it is just a command, the error presumably says what is wrong, typically the error message will be something like `xetex is not recognised as a command` have you installed texlive or miktex as well as texmaker?

Comment: Yes I have miktex also installed, I think it hase something to do with the path but I dont know how to fix it

Comment: what was the error message, has texmaker found the path to xetex that you installed with miktex?

Comment: when I open Latex an than go to options and the first window that opens there are like two fields at the top and they are empty and I dont know what to write in there

Comment: I have never used texmaker, I tagged your question that way, but I guess a texmaker user will answer.  Although it would help if you showed where your xetex is. eg did you install miktex in admin or user mode or both?

Comment: how can I show you this, I´m sorry but I´m new in Latex and english isn´t my mothertounge

Comment: I have made a screenshot maybe this willl help you to understand what I mean

Comment: Don't worry your English is clear enough, just wait until the morning (it's late in the evening in Europe where most people answering are located)  a texmaker user will probably answer if you wait a bit. there is an existing answer about setting up common editors I will see if I can find it...

Comment: see this answer (which is about pdflatex but xelatex should be similar) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481068/no-pdflatex-exe-file-in-miktex-directory